# How to randomly shuffle data and target in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 4D array training images, whose dimensions correspond to `(num_images, channels, width, height)`. I also have a 2D target labels whose dimensions correspond to `(num_images, class_number)`. When training, I want to randomly shuffle the data by using `random.shuffle`, but how can I keep the labels shuffled in the same order as my images?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want a numpy-only solution, you can just reindex the second array on the first, assuming you've got the same image numbers in both:

```
In [67]: train = np.arange(20).reshape(4,5).T

In [68]: target = np.hstack([np.arange(5).reshape(5,1), np.arange(100, 105).reshape(5,1)])

In [69]: train
Out[69]:
array([[ 0,  5, 10, 15],
       [ 1,  6, 11, 16],
       [ 2,  7, 12, 17],
       [ 3,  8, 13, 18],
       [ 4,  9, 14, 19]])

In [70]: target
Out[70]:
array([[  0, 100],
       [  1, 101],
       [  2, 102],
       [  3, 103],
       [  4, 104]])

In [71]: np.random.shuffle(train)

In [72]: target[train[:,0]]
Out[72]:
array([[  2, 102],
       [  3, 103],
       [  1, 101],
       [  4, 104],
       [  0, 100]])

In [73]: train
Out[73]:
array([[ 2,  7, 12, 17],
       [ 3,  8, 13, 18],
       [ 1,  6, 11, 16],
       [ 4,  9, 14, 19],
       [ 0,  5, 10, 15]])
```

Answer (score 92):

```py
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import numpy as np

X = np.array([
  [0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1], 
  [2, 2, 2], 
  [3, 3, 3], 
  [4, 4, 4]
])
y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
X, y = shuffle(X, y)
print(X)
print(y)
```

Output:

```py
[[1 1 1]
 [3 3 3]
 [0 0 0]
 [2 2 2]
 [4 4 4]] 

[1 3 0 2 4]
```

Comment: To help readers understand your solution, consider including a short description of your code and how it solves the posted question

Comment: @HenryWoody I think the the code is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 14):

There is another easy way to do that. Let us suppose that there are total `N` images. Then we can do the following:

```
from random import shuffle

ind_list = [i for i in range(N)]
shuffle(ind_list)
train_new  = train[ind_list, :,:,:]
target_new = target[ind_list,]
```

Comment: Instead of `[i for i in range(N)]` you could use `list(range(N))`.

Comment: This is a good solution for shuffle more than 2 data structures. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a sync/ unison shuffle you can use the following func.

```
def unisonShuffleDataset(a, b):
    assert len(a) == len(b)
    p = np.random.permutation(len(a))
    return a[p], b[p]
```

the one above is only for 2 numpy. One can extend to more than 2 by adding the number of input vars on the func. and also on the return of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, you could also randomly generate a number for each dimension of your array with

```
random.randint(a, b)  #a and b are the extremes of your array
```

which would select randomly amongst your objects.

Comment: As `random.randint(a, b)` does not guarantee that the number generated is not the same as previously generated before, so there would a manual work to keep track that every time you are generating a unique number, till all the data is covered.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same seed to build the random generator multiple times to shuffle different arrays:

```
>>> seed = np.random.SeedSequence()
>>> arrays = [np.arange(10).repeat(i).reshape(10, -1) for i in range(1, 4)]
>>> for ar in arrays:
...     np.random.default_rng(seed).shuffle(ar)
...
>>> arrays
[array([[1],
        [2],
        [7],
        [8],
        [0],
        [4],
        [3],
        [6],
        [9],
        [5]]),
 array([[1, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [7, 7],
        [8, 8],
        [0, 0],
        [4, 4],
        [3, 3],
        [6, 6],
        [9, 9],
        [5, 5]]),
 array([[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [7, 7, 7],
        [8, 8, 8],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [4, 4, 4],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [6, 6, 6],
        [9, 9, 9],
        [5, 5, 5]])]
```